# Saving text and checkbox state in custom list

Tags: java, android, checkbox, custom-lists, lost-focus

I am making a custom list and I want to save the text of some TextFile which is in R.id.quantity.

I also want to save the state of a checkbox. I tried to manage checked state of a checkbox in a list.

The List contains other view controls. I have put them in a Viewholder class. I am initializing qtyTxtV with some initial array value, once an event occurs in this code the value of the array changes but the list contents gets erased. Please help out.

Now this code is giving me a null pointer exception:

```
class MyAdapter1 extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
ArrayList<Integer> price = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
public static HashMap<Integer, String> myList = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvQuantityName, tvPrice, tvDishName;
    public ImageView imv1, imv2, imv3, imv4, imv5;
    public EditText edtQty;
    public CheckBox chkAdd;
}
public MyAdapter1(VegDetail vegDetail, ArrayList<String> names2,
        ArrayList<Integer> price2) {
    this.context = vegDetail;
    this.names = names2;
    this.price = price2;
    }
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return names.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
@SuppressWarnings("null")
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    // View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        holder.edtQty = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        holder.imv1 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.star1);
        holder.imv2 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.star2);
        holder.imv3 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.star3);
        holder.imv4 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.star4);
        holder.imv5 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.star5);
        holder.tvDishName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        holder.tvPrice = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.price1);
        holder.tvQuantityName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.qtyTxtV);
        holder.chkAdd = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.chkAdd);
        EditText edtQty = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        edtQty.setText(VegDetail.qtyArray[position].toString());
        CheckBox chkAdd = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.chkAdd);
        chkAdd.setSelected(VegDetail.chkArray[position]);           
        holder.edtQty.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s,
                    final int start, final int before, final int count) {
            }
            public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
                int newValue;
                final String boxContents = s.toString();
                if (!boxContents.isEmpty()) {
                    try {
                        newValue = Integer.parseInt(boxContents);
                        VegDetail.qtyArray[position] = newValue;
                    } catch (final Exception exc) {
                        VegDetail.qtyArray[position] = 0;
                    } finally {
                    }
                } else {
                    VegDetail.qtyArray[position] = 0;
                }
            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(final CharSequence s,
                    final int start, final int count, final int after) {
            }
        });

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    CheckBox chkAdd=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.chkAdd);
    chkAdd.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            //VegDetail is another class where I gonna use checked list's states
            VegDetail.chkArray[position] = isChecked;               
        }
    });
    final TextView tv1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.price1);
    final TextView tvQty = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
    tv1.setText(names.get(position));
    tv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context,
                    "itme name is=>" + tv1.getText().toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    tv2.setText("Rs:" + price.get(position));   
    return row;
}
}
```

Comment: paste logcat trace... it would be pointing Nullpointer exception at some line no.  , specify that line no. in your code too

Comment: at line  holder.imv1 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.star1);

Answer (score 0):

The NPE must be at  line :

```
    holder.edtQty = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
```

since `holder` is `NULL`  as you have just defined above...`ViewHolder holder = null`